# Why is Django template loop nesting my divs?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, django-templates, nested-loops

I am using Bootstrap with Django and want the .item-container.col-md-4 to be three boxes inside a row. It should look something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item-container col-md-4> Stuff</div>
    <div class="item-container col-md-4> Another Thing</div>
    <div class="item-container col-md-4> This Next One</div>
</div>
```

I am getting something more like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item-container col-md-4> Stuff
        <div class="item-container col-md-4> Another Thing</div>
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="item-container col-md-4> This Next One</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
   <div class="item-container col-md-4">
     {{ product.someinfo }}
  </div>
   {% if forloop.counter != products|length  %}
    </div>
    <script> console.log('not last', {{ products|length }}, {{forloop.counter}} ); </script>
   {% endif %}

   {% if forloop.last %}
    </div>
   <script> console.log('by 3', {{ products|length }}, {{forloop.counter}} );</script>

{% elif forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
   <script> console.log('last', {{ products|length }}, {{forloop.counter}} );</script>
   <div class='row'>
{% endif %}

{% empty %}

<div class="nothing-found">
    Nothing found.
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to remove the extra `<div>` in the line shown below

```
   {% if forloop.counter != products|length  %}
    </div>    <----------------------- THIS
    <script> console.log('not last', {{ products|length }}, {{forloop.counter}} ); </script>
   {% endif %}
```

I would recommend rewriting your template to something simpler

```
{% if products %}
<div class="row">
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="item-container col-md-4"> {{ product.someinfo }} </div>
  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
</div>
<div class="row">
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="nothing-found">
    Nothing found.
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this and my divs are still not lining up. They are staggering. Could this be caused by an extra or unclosed div before this template or is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: The existing logic seems too complex and there is very likely an extra div somewhere.