# How to make dynamic content display across a grid using Django with Bootstrap?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Django project with a homepage similar to StackOverflow's: it displays snippets of incoming user-generated content in a single main column. However, I'd like those content snippets to display across rows of 3 filling up the homepage (think [Pinterest pinboard page][2] or a grid layout blog).

I'm using Bootstrap's grid system, but realized I don't know the right combination of Python/Django template magic + Bootstrap to get that incoming content to populate across a grid. Can someone spell this out for me?

I want...

```
            {% for question in questions.paginator.page %}
            {% question_list_item question %}
            {% endfor %}
```

...to have the repeating effect of

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-4">
                item 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                item 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                item 3
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-4">
                item 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                item 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                item 3
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** I was able to get this working (with a little column-count variation for responsiveness) using the following, but I'm a beginner so please let me know if there's a better solution.

```
                    <div class="row">
                        {% for question in questions.paginator.page %}
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            {% question_list_item question %}
                        </div>
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could post code of your `models.py`?

Comment: You can also stick all questions in a single row. Floats will wrap into a new row just because no more than 12 columns fit next to each other in a single container.

Comment: Looks like the same thing (forloop.counter|divisibleby) was recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21625264/317110

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and here is my solution:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  {% for question in questions.paginator.page %}
  {%  if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %} 
    <div class="col-md-4">
      {{ question.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% if not forloop.last %} 
  <div class="row">
  {% endif %}
  {% else %} 
    <div class="col-md-4">
      {{ question.title }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest case is if you have two separate user-contributed pieces of information that need go in two columns; then you can do something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      {{ usercontent.thing_a }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      {{ usercontent.thing_b }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the user is entering stuff in one big monolithic block, you'll need to figure out how yo want to split it--is there some marker in the text you can use to divide into two pieces, and then do it like above? If so, you might split it with Python's `split` or use a regex.

Or is this running text, like the body of an article, and you want it to divide in half? If it's the latter case, I'd have the text show up in one Bootstrap column, but use CSS3's "column" property to show as two columns.

Comment: Ah, I think using the phrase 'multiple columns' when what I meant is 'rows' was unnecessarily confusing. Sorry about that. I don't actually want to add different information to each column, but have the same populate across a grid (imagine if Twitter displayed tweets in boxes all over a Pinterest board instead of in a single-column timeline). The solutions I think I want seem to involve {% cycle... or {% if forloop... but I can't figure it out myself. I added more info in my question if that's helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use a JavaScript Grid, rendered on the client side, like the Shield UI [Grid widget](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/basic-usage). You can even tie it to a server-side API for retrieving the data and performing other operations like editing, deletion, sorting, grouping, etc.

A complete tutorial and source code for that can be seen [here](https://www.shieldui.com/blogs/django-integration-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

See this resource on how to use Pagination with Class-Based List Views (Django & Bootstrap):
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from questions.models import Question

class QuestionListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'your_app_name/questions.html'  
    context_object_name = 'questions'  
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
```

**questions.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Tag</th>
  <th>Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for question in questions %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ question.item }}</td>
    <td>{{ question.tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ question.date }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

{% if is_paginated %}
<ul class="pagination">
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
  <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
{% else %}
  <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
{% endif %}
{% for i in paginator.page_range %}
  {% if page_obj.number == i %}
    <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>     </span></li>
  {% else %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% if page_obj.has_next %}
  <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
 {% else %}
  <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
 {% endif %}
 </ul>
 {% endif %}
```